# How to change the datatype of column in dask dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, types, dask

I have a column in my dask dataframe whose datatype is integer I want to change it to a float datatype, how can I do such an operation.

```
fid_price_df.head(3)

    fid selling_price
0   98101   439.00
1   67022   419.00
2   131142  299.00
```

In the above dask dataframe I need to change the 'fid' column into float datatype.

```
>>>type(fid_price_df)
dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
fid_price_df['column_name_you_want_to_convert']=fid_price_df['column_name_you_want_to_convert'].astype(float)
```

so in this case,

```
fid_price_df['fid']=fid_price_df['fid'].astype(float)
```